# Laravel shows parameter name instead of value (when using optional parameter in route)

Tags: php, google-maps, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

I've got a form where a user can enter a start location, when submitting he will go to a map centered on this location.  He can also just skip this step and go to the map directly.  (this is the simplified version to skip the whole background story)

This is the first piece of code, when the user has used the form it will take the start location from the form and redirect to the map: (never mind the planning variable, it will always be 'own' for the purpose of this case)

```
Route::post('InitiateUserTrip', ['as' => 'InitiateUserTrip', function(WelcomeFormRequest $request) 
{
    if (Input::get('planning') == 'own') {
        return Redirect::route('Map',array('startLocation', Input::get('startLocation')));
    } else {
      return view('welcome');
    }
} ]);
```

This is the map route, the startLocation is optional as explained above.  (API key would be my personal API KEY.) What I see happening here is that the debugbar is showing 'startLocation' instead of the value of the parameter.  (name instead of value)

```
Route::get('Map/{startLocation?}', ['as' => 'Map', function($startLocation = null)
{
    $map = new Map('API KEY',$startLocation,'GMainMap');    
    $googleMap = $map->getMap();
    $node = new Node();
    $node->loadBySelection('ALL');
    $nodes = $node->getNodes();
    \Debugbar::info("Map: " . $startLocation);
    return View::make('map')->with('map', $googleMap)
                            ->with('nodes',$nodes)
                            ->with('startLocation',$startLocation);
}]);
```

I started playing with the URL to see what was going on.
Assuming the user entered 'Miami' as startLocation this would result in following URL:

http://laravel.dev/Map/startLocation?Miami => Debugbar would show 'startLocation'

When I modify the URL myself to 
http://laravel.dev/Map/Miami => Debugbar would show 'Miami'

It's not just Debugbar that would show wrong contents.  I try to geocode based on this variable and it fails because it sees the contents as 'startLocation' as well.

I may be able to solve this problem by creating two routes, one with and one without parameter but I suppose I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: why you are using "?" in routes,remove this

Comment: @ImtiazPabel The `?` means that the route parameter is optional and totally valid.

Comment: Gotta keep in mind that route parameters are not the same as `GET` parameters (from the query string following `?` in the URL). `/Map/Miami` would correctly return `"Miami"` for `$startLocation`, the same as `/Map/startloaction?Miami` would *correctly* show `"startLocation"` for `$startLocation`. Pretty much you're trying to use both URL and `GET` parameters when you really should just pick one.

Comment: Would somebody be so kind to explain why this question is downvoted?  Maybe it's a newbie question but I'm trying to learn and I think everybody makes stupid mistakes at times. Also I did my best to formulate a clear question, clearly describing the environment, situation and problem.  So please help me here, just by downvoting this question I will not learn how to improve my posts for the future. (I already looked at 'how to ask')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error within your route call

```
Redirect::route('Map',array('startLocation', Input::get('startLocation')));
```

Should be this:

```
Redirect::route('Map',array(Input::get('startLocation')));
```

You dont need to specify key in route call, the array is paired with parameters in given route based on their position in array, eg. first item in array to first parameter in route, 2nd item in array to 2nd parameter in route etc.

Comment: Just to make it a bit clearer, using keys is okay but the way it was attempted is still wrong.  `array('startLocation' => Input::get('startLocation'))`

Comment: I originally wanted to advise this, but my solution requires less code :) Both are correct of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes work as expected. Keep in mind that **{startLocation?}** is not part of the URL, but a placeholder that will be **replaced** by the actual value of the parameter.

Therefore, your **Route::get('Map/{startLocation?}', ...);** route says that **startLocation** parameter value is whatever comes right after the **Map/**. So if you go to **Map/startLocation?Miami**, **startLocation** string is taken as the value of the parameter.

The easiest way to serve both **/Map** and **/Map/startLocation?Miami** URLs is to define 2 routes:

```
Route::get('Map', ...);
Route::get('Map/startLocation?{startLocation}', ...);
```